# Update an Object in indexed db by ignoring a value

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have written the below code

```
updatePublication(projectName, publicationId, publicationObj, callback) {
  let self = this;
  this.initDatabase(function (db) {
    let tx = self.db.transaction(self.PUBLICATIONS, self.READ_WRITE);
    let store = tx.objectStore(self.PUBLICATIONS);
    let index = store.index(self.PROJECT_NAME);

    let request3 = index.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(projectName));
    console.log("hrere");
    request3.onsuccess = function () {
      let cursor = request3.result;
      if (cursor) {
        let updateObject = cursor.value;
        if (updateObject.publicationID == publicationId) {
          updateObject.publicationObject = publicationObj;
          cursor.update(updateObject);
          callback(publicationId);
        }
        cursor.continue();
      } else {
        callback(publicationId);
      }
    };
  });
}
```

But this give error:
[image]

I checked the cause of error. It is beacuse ,  publicationObj which is passed has an object named _requestObjectBuilder which is of the type Subscriber.

used somewhere in the code like this:
_requestObjectBuilder = interval(1000).pipe(tap(() => {}));

Is there any way i can modify my updatePublication code to ignore this value?
Does indexed db support a query for ignoring a value and saving the data?

Note: If i set publicationObj._requestObjectBuilder = undefined, the data gets saved to indexedDB. But this breaks the functionality  where _requestObjectBuilder is used.

Comment: I cannot even deep copy the value having _requestObjectBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by cloning the object and setting it to undefined

```
let clonedObject = Object.assign({}, publicationObject);
clonedObject._requestObjectBuilder = undefined;
```

Now i am updating the clonedObject